# What is Paramahamsa Vishwananda's stance on homosexuality?

Tags: homosexuality

Paramahamsa Vishwananda, the founding acharya of the Vaishnava organisation Bhakti Marga and considered an reincarnation of Paramahamsa Yogananda. Initiated in Sri Vaishnavism, he is known to not shy away from adopting customs of other Vaishnavite Sampradayas. In fact, he is one of the rarest Sri Vaishnava acharyas that worship Shiva. As He is notable for taking liberal stances on controversial issues (and as a result, is considered very controversial to the Polish media).

However, there have been sexual allegations by his male ex-disciples on him. Now, since he keeps liberal views on issues including on sex, what is Paramahamsa Vishwananda's view of homosexuality?

Comment: Except for manu smriti there are no scripture which say anything about homosexuality, I guess it's ok in restricted sense, but I hate the vanity and overreacting surrounding lgbtq community. Manu smriti also doesn't allow samudrolanghana and widow remarriage but then again who follows that nowadays.

Comment: Close voters should know what is opinion based and which is not. If you can vote doiesn't mean you should.

Comment: @AnubhavJha Not just Manu Smriti, lots of Dharma Shastras say it.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan yes, others too say to do penace, but not as strictly as manu smriti, masturbation and sex for enjoyment is also banned, even contraceptives are banned but some of these things are very important for healthy living, we don't want to overpopulate the earth afterall.

Comment: @AnubhavJha We should follow Dharma Shastras and then let the gods take care of the consequences.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan well, dharma itself is a very subjective term, I think the rituals in srutis are enough for religious dharma, we must have some sense of dharma and conscience for earth too right, if there is matr dharma, Pitr dharma, kshatriya dharma there must be some dharma for nature and bhu devi too.

Comment: @AnubhavJha Morality is objective, not subjective.  Violating Dharma Shastras leads to unseen negative consequences that are far worse than the visible consequences that come from following them.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan anyway, according to a commentor on dharma sastra, gavyena means cow product, and not beef as you mentioned in question of anushana parva.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24718/manu-3-271-which-translators-commentators-interpret-gavyena-as-beef-cow-mea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is fine with it.  [Here](https://mobile.twitter.com/vishwananda/status/742701374211817472?lang=en) is what he said on Twitter a couple years ago:

> loveislove no matter how you express it, love is #God n God is #love, love doesn't know weather one is #Gay or #Straight be always yourself

And by the way, he's not a Sri Vaishnava Acharya, he's just someone who's received Samashrayanam from the Sri Vaishnava Sampradayam.

Comment: Does Samashrayanam make you an official Sri Vaishnava?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Yes, it does.

Comment: And is worshipping other deities forbidden after Samashrayanam?

Comment: No, Vadakalais perform two rituals, Samashrayanam and Bharanyasam, and after Bharanyasam they promise not to worship other gods.  But after Samashrayanam there's no such promise.  After Samashrayanam the promises are mainly about not eating meat and the like.

Comment: Are people downvoting because there's a problem with my answer, or because they disagree with Vishwananda's views?  For the record, I too disagree with his views.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I have not downvoted but People including me don't endorse homosexuality. Some might have thought you are in support.