# What is Vivekananda's / his disciples' / Ramakrishna Math's stance on homosexuality?

Tags: sin, vivekananda, homosexuality

What were Swami Vivekananda's views on homosexuality? What did he preach on this topic?

If he did not discuss this topic, what is the current view of his disciple-acharyas at the [Ramakrishna Math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramakrishna_Math)?

What is the official position of [Ramakrishna Math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramakrishna_Math) on this? Does it consider it a sin?

---

My question is similar to *[What is Paramahamsa Vishwananda's stance on homosexuality?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24716/2995)* which unfortunately as of now remains closed as "primarily opinion-based."

Comment: That question you linked was not primarily opinion based. It has got 4 votes and failed to get that last vote to reopen.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be reopened. Some users are simply voting to close questions they don't like (blatant misuse of voting power).

Comment: @sv, do you want to know each famous personality's stance on this topic ? maybe you can combine all those questions into one. btw, eunuchs have always been there in the world. there is no need to hate them and say they shouldn't exist, nor to take pride in their actions and justify them either.

Comment: @ram 'do you want to know each famous personality's stance on this topic?' - yes, especially if some sects see it as a sin and others not, also makes easy for tagging/searching.

Comment: Lust and greed are what bind people to the world. Lust takes a different form for every person as does greed - every person's heart is different. To become spiritual one must give up lust and greed as it appears to them. Even householders are given to give these up. One form of lust is no better than another form.

Comment: "One form of lust is no better than another form."-- Lust that is between a man and woman is natural order so it is not bad.. if that had to be bad, we feeling hungry or sleepy or thirsty would have been bad too.. A man and woman are created like that so that they come together for the sacred purpose of procreation..what is that sacred purpose when a man lusts a man?? @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: @Rickross you are misquoting me. My statement was prefaced by "To become spiritual". Even a married person who lusts remains bound. The farther you walk in one direction, the farther away you are from your starting point. Walk to God, it doesn't matter what your starting point is, just walk towards God.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda So is this post only discussing whether homosexuality is an obstacle for spiritual progress? Ur comment says both homosexuality and the normal sexual tendency are equal as regards spiritual progress.. what's the proof of that statement? Come up with something from the scriptures.. how can the desire for eating delicious foods and the desire for eating foods that are unfit to be eaten be considered equal?? They are not equal in any ways.

Answer (score 10):

The following is [an excerpt](http://www.advaitaashrama.org/Content/pb/2015/092015.pdf) from the monthly journal [*Prabuddha Bharata*](http://www.advaitaashrama.org/pbgenesis/) published by the [Ramakrishna Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramakrishna_Order). This indicates they don't view the homosexual person in bad light. And it's much more important for a spiritual aspirant to have an *asexual* orientation.

> **EDITORIAL**
>
> **Beyond Bodies**
>
> ...   ...
>
> The restraint of the senses becomes important
>   in our spiritual lives in that it helps us to take our
>   mind away from our body and fix it on our destination,
>   the Atman. Almost all bodily pursuits
>   are playgrounds for the senses. And the most active
>   and titillating to the senses is the playground
>   of bodily contact, the playground of sex. No true
>   spiritual tradition or spiritual teacher would say
>   that sexual activity or sexuality in the past disqualifies
>   a person from becoming a spiritual aspirant.
>   All the same, no true spiritual tradition or spiritual
>   teacher would say that sexual activity or sexuality
>   *is* the spiritual path. That is the most convenient
>   stand one can take. Just because I cannot control
>   the senses, just because I cannot control the sexual
>   urge does not mean that I be controlled by the
>   senses and that I be urged by sexuality. **Sexuality is 
>   *not* spirituality. One's sexual orientation or sexual
>   preferences have nothing to do with spirituality.** If
>   that were true, then cats, dogs, and rabbits would
>   have been the most spiritual. And rabbits would
>   have been spiritual seers! The Atman and the
>   senses, God and the senses, cannot be worshipped
>   together. You are either spiritual or sexual. You
>   cannot be both. The world has seen thousands of
>   centuries of spiritual and religious life but is yet to
>   see a person who could control one's internal and
>   external environments through the power of spirituality
>   and yet thrived in expressing one's sexuality.
>   You would have to put off one to get the other.
>
> Spirituality is the search for our true nature. It
>   is a path open and inevitable to all of us. Sexuality
>   is the expression of one's carnal desires. This is a
>   trait primitive and instinctual in all of us but it is
>   not inevitable. **Spiritual life is for everyone. Even
>   for people who had a sexual expression or a distinct
>   sexual orientation.** But, if one has to become
>   spiritual one has to leave one's sexuality or sexual
>   orientation. Just like the satisfaction one gets
>   from eating one's favourite food after a long time
>   is not spiritual illumination, understanding or
>   finding one's natural sexual orientation is *not* spiritual
>   realisation. If it were so, all the spiritual traditions
>   would become big lies and all one would
>   need to become spiritual was a session with one's
>   therapist! Spirituality or self-realisation is not just
>   'coming out of the closet'. It is going beyond all
>   orientations, not finding another one.
>
> To set upon the journey of spirituality, the
>   journey to realise one's true nature, is an informed
>   choice. It is a state when you want to go beyond
>   the body, beyond all orientations. **We should remember
>   that just like there are heterosexual and
>   homosexual orientations, there is an asexual orientation,
>   the orientation of the spiritual aspirant**,
>   who does not want to be bogged down by the pulls
>   of the flesh but wants to transcend them and realise
>   one's transcendent nature, the Atman.
>
> ---
>
> *Prabuddha Bharata or Awakened India 
>
>   A monthly journal of the Ramakrishna Order started by Swami Vivekananda in 1896 
>
>   September 2015, Vol. 120, No. 9*

From the same journal ([January, 2011](http://advaitaashrama.org/Content/pb/2011/012011.pdf)):

> The Practice of Modern Yoga: Sri Ramakrishna's Four Contributions
>
> Dr Christopher Key Chapple
>
> **Deconstruction of Gender Identity**
>
> ...
>
> On several occasions I have assigned Christopher
>   Isherwood's *[My Guru and His Disciple](https://books.google.com/books?id=xX3WAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=isbn%3A1466853301&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)* to
>   my university classes. **This narrative includes the
>   author's own struggle to overcome homoerotic
>   urges. Reflecting a general acceptance of gender
>   ambiguity, his guru Swami Prabhavananda
>   quietly advised him to see the face of God in
>   the object(s) of his affection.** This advice, given
>   at a time when homosexuals were arrested, imprisoned,
>   and subjected to harsh treatments,
>   including electric shock therapy, came as great
>   solace to Isherwood. His friend and neighbour
>   UCLA psychologist [Dr Evelyn Hooker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evelyn_Hooker), inspired
>   in part by Isherwood's honesty and fine human
>   qualities, undertook a path-breaking study
>   proving that homosexuals were often mentally
>   well-adjusted and productive members of society.
>   Her research eventually resulted in the declassification
>   of homosexuality as an illness by
>   the American Psychiatric Association in 1974
>   and the decriminalization of homosexual acts
>   in most states in the US—and most recently in
>   the Indian capital territory as well.
>
> Classical India has long accepted the notion
>   of a 'third sex', *napumsaka*, and has tolerated
>   the existence of non-standard gender identity
>   communities, the *hijra*. A small but not insignificant
>   community of Vedanta and yoga practitioners
>   in the US have taken inspiration from
>   Christopher Isherwood. More than one student
>   has confided in me the relief they have
>   felt when they discovered a model for spirituality
>   that did not condemn their sexual orientation.
>   As a professor, however, it is my duty to
>   remind them that true spirituality lies beyond
>   all identities.

Comment: "it's much more important for a spiritual aspirant to have an asexual orientation." True Indeed.